# Compatibility condition for Poisson's equation - Divergence theorem

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, poissons-equation

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be open and bounded. Given the Poissons equation with Neumann-boundary, e.g.

$$-\Delta u = f \quad \text{and}\quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=g, $$ we must require the compatibility condition 
$$\int_\Omega f \, \mathrm dx + \int_{\partial \Omega} g \, \mathrm dS=0$$ which follows from the divergence theorem:

$$\int_{\Omega} f \, \mathrm dx=-\int_{\Omega} \mathrm{div}(\nabla u) \, \mathrm dx=-\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta} \, \mathrm dS=- \int_{\partial \Omega} g \, dS.$$

But I read that the divergence theorem requires compactness of $\Omega$, how is using the theorem justified?

Comment: Perhaps compactness of $\bar \Omega$?

Comment: @Tesla: You have probably misread, and *relative* compactness was required (i.e. the compactness of the closure). You have probably skipped the word "relatively" from "relatively-compact".